# My CS50 Credit code is not producing any output after adding a check for type of credit card

Tags: c, cs50

The calculating if the card is valid is correct as I tested that and the code performed correctly there, so I removed that section from under the Do section loop to appease stackoverflow. The problem comes from deciding what type of card was used; the program does nothing and waits for the next command in the console. I'm just not seeing what the issue is. Below is my code and I tested with card number 4003600000000014, the result should've printed out "Visa":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Array to store the individual digits of the card
    long card, card_copy;
    int pos = 0, sum = 0, card_id;

    do
    {
        card = get_long("CC#: ");
        card_copy = card;
        while(card != 0)
        {
            if(pos % 2 != 0)
            {
                int temp = 2 * (card % 10);
                // For #s > 9
                if(temp > 9)
                {
                    sum += (temp % 10 + temp / 10);
                }
                else
                {
                    sum += temp;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sum += card % 10;
            }
        card /= 10; // Divides card # to remove the decimal place
                    // and moves to the next digit in CC
        pos++;
        }
    }
    while(card != 0);

    if(sum % 10 == 0)
    {
       // Divides card to only have the first 2 digits
       card_id = card_copy / (pow(10, pos - 1));

       // Divides card to only have first digit; 4 for Visa
       int visa_id = card_copy / (pow(10, pos - 2));

       // 16-digit; start with 51, 52, 53, 54, or 55
       if(pos == 15 && (card_id >= 51 && card_id <= 55))
       {
           printf("MasterCard");
       }
       // 15-digit; start with 34 or 37
       else if(pos == 14 && (card_id == 34 || card_id == 37))
       {
           printf("American Express");
       }
       // 13-digit; start with 4
       else if(pos == 12 && visa_id == 4)
       {
           printf("Visa");
       }
       // 16-digit; start with 4
       else if(pos == 15 && visa_id == 4)
       {
           printf("Visa");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid: %d\n", sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your first do-while loop keeps prompting for CC# and writes the entered number to the same variable until the user enters 0. Is that what you want? If you just want to prompt for one number, why is it a loop?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right code now? It changed pretty drastically since the last time I looked.

Comment: I've edited my code to add in the loop

Comment: Try learning how to use a debugger.   That makes it much, much easier to debug code.

Comment: Yes. Use a debugger and check your values each step along the way in your code. Or at least sprinkle in some printf statements to examine intermediate values. These values should make sense according to the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: Yes, this is my full code, stack didn't allow all of it before. I tested the do while by having it followed by a simple if else to print valid or invalid. The issue is with the card type check

Comment: you should make sure of your indices. Use "scaffolding" (print pos) along the code to make sure there is no off-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

The long type has a maximum value of 2147483647. This wouldn't hold the shortest card type I know which is 12 digits.
Either change to `unsigned long long` or better still use a string.

Comment: The size of `long` is implementation-defined, and is 64 bits on some platforms. But yeah, don’t rely on that, and in any case use a string instead.

Comment: I've worked on payment systems and they've all used strings for card numbers. You only need the first 6 digits (known as the BIN range) for the card type, which will keep card numbers off your system. Unless you're processing card details in which case you really need to look at PCI-DSS compliance.